# Logic issue on reading ALL data from the from the listbox that is coming from thread in c#

Tags: c#, arraylist, c#-4.0, telnet

I am modifying to first question attempt.

I need help passing the data from a listbox and pass it to another method so every time the listbox gets data add it from the tread, it should also send that data to my new method and it to the my list because in that method I will be doing some parsing because the data from the listbox is a long string barcode but I don't need help on parsing the data because I can do that, the part I need help only is to pass the data from thread that is passing it to the listbox it should also be send to my method ReadAllData() so in that method I will received the data and then I will do the parsing the make a return.

Here is the method where the listbox is stored and receives the data from a thread from telnet port 23

Here is the code I need to send the data from the lst_BarcodeScan to the method ReadAllData method and store to my list.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using System.Security.Authentication.ExtendedProtection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BarcodeReceivingApp
{
    public class TelnetConnection
    {
        private Thread _readWriteThread;
        private TcpClient _client;
        private NetworkStream _networkStream;
        private string _hostname;
        private int _port;
        private BarcodeReceivingForm _form;
        private bool _isExiting = false;

        public TelnetConnection(string hostname, int port)
        {
            this._hostname = hostname;
            this._port = port;
        }

        public TelnetConnection()
        {

        }

        public void ServerSocket(string ip, int port, BarcodeReceivingForm f)
        {

            this._form = f;
            try
            {
                _client = new TcpClient(ip, port);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(@"Failed to connect to server");
                return;
            }


            _networkStream = _client.GetStream();
            _readWriteThread = new Thread(ReadWrite);
            //_readWriteThread = new Thread(() => ReadWrite(f));
            _readWriteThread.Start();
        }


        public void Exit()
        {
            _isExiting = true;
        }

        public void ReadWrite()
        {

            var received = "";
            do
            {
                received = Read();
                if (received == null)
                    break;

                if (_form.lst_BarcodeScan.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    _form.lst_BarcodeScan.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                    {
                        _form.lst_BarcodeScan.Items.Add(received + Environment.NewLine);
                    }));
                }    

            } while (!_isExiting);



            CloseConnection();


        }

    public List<string> ReadAllData()
    {
        var obtainData = new List<string>();



       return obtainData;
    }

        public string Read()
        {
            var data = new byte[1024];
            var received = "";

            var size = _networkStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            if (size == 0)
                return null;

            received = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, size);

            return received;
        }

        public void CloseConnection()
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"Closed Connection",@"Important Message");
            _networkStream.Close();
            _client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Main class that will call the methods from the telnetconnection class or any other classes I will add.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BarcodeReceivingApp
{
    public partial class BarcodeReceivingForm : Form
    {
        //GLOBAL VARIABLES
        private const string Hostname = "myip";
        private const int Port = 23;
        private TelnetConnection _connection;


        public BarcodeReceivingForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }

        private void btn_ConnectT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _connection = new TelnetConnection(Hostname, Port);
            _connection.ServerSocket(Hostname, Port, this);

        }

        private void btn_StopConnection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //_connection = new TelnetConnection(Hostname, Port);
            //_connection.ServerSocket(Hostname, Port, this);
            _connection.Exit();
        }

        private void btn_RemoveItemFromListAt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (var i = lst_BarcodeScan.SelectedIndices.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                lst_BarcodeScan.Items.RemoveAt(lst_BarcodeScan.SelectedIndices[i]);
            }
        }

        private void BarcodeReceivingForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lst_BarcodeScan.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple;
        }

        private void btn_ApplicationSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var bcSettingsForm = new BarcodeReceivingSettingsForm();
            bcSettingsForm.Show();
        }

        private void btn_ClearBarcodeList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lst_BarcodeScan.Items.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: any help on this? or should I change anything to make more sense in my question? let me know and I can do that.

Comment: Hello anybody can take a look to my issue?

Comment: Are you trying to read ALL the data from the listbox and parse it once or every time the thread add items to it ?

Comment: that is exactly what I need

Comment: which one you need to do because i mention 2 in my comment. Edit your question and specify which you are trying to do.

Comment: no problem I will update my question description

Comment: @Franck I modified the question description and also some of the body description please take a look

Comment: any update on this I change the description of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to implement without adding more complexity to the thread is to simply raise an event on the `listbox` when and item is added to it. The problem is that the `listbox` do no have any events that allow to do that but you can create your own version with a dozen lines of code.

The goal is to create a derived control of the `listbox` then you add to it a method to trigger a custom event when an item is added and bingo.

Here's the custom `listbox` class with the custom `EventArgs`.

```
// custom override class over the list box so we can create an event when items are added
public class ListBoxWithEvents : ListBox
{
    // the event you need to bind to know when items are added
    public event EventHandler<ListBoxItemEventArgs> ItemAdded;

    // method to call to add items instead of lst.Items.Add(x);
    public void AddItem(object data)
    {
        // add the item normally to the internal list
        var index = Items.Add(data);

        // invoke the event to notify the binded handlers
        InvokeItemAdded(index);
    }

    public void InvokeItemAdded(int index)
    {
        // invoke the event if binded anywhere
        ItemAdded?.Invoke(this, new ListBoxItemEventArgs(index));
    }
}

// basic event handler that will hold the index of the item added
public class ListBoxItemEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int Index { get; set; } = -1;
    public ListBoxItemEventArgs(int index)
    {
        Index = index;
    }       
}
```

Now you need to change your `listbox` on your `form` with the `ListBoxWithEvents` instead. You have 2 ways to do this but i'll give you the easiest. Compile your code and go in the design window for the `form`. In your toolbox you should have the `ListBoxWithEvents` control now and you can simply drag and drop in your `form` and replace the one you have. Since it derive from the `listbox` all it has is extra features. It didn't lose anything it had before.

Now you need to change 2 things. In your `form` select the new `ListBoxWithEvents` control and go in the properties events and you will find the new event called `ItemAdded` you can double click that and it should create an event like the following. I have also thrown in a sample `MessageBox` that display all you will need.

```
private void ListBox1_ItemAdded(object sender, ListBoxItemEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Item was added at index " + e.Index + " and the value is " + listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString());
}
```

Finally in order to trigger that event you need to use the new method `lst.AddItem(object);` instead of `lst.Items.Add(object);` so according to your sample code you need to change this :

```
_form.lst_BarcodeScan.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
{
    _form.lst_BarcodeScan.Items.Add(received + Environment.NewLine);
}));
```

to this :

```
_form.lst_BarcodeScan.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
{
    _form.lst_BarcodeScan.AddItem(received + Environment.NewLine);
}));
```

Try it and now you should have that event fire every time something is added to the list.

Since you are pretty new to programming i find it important to mention that this event will trigger on the UI thread and not the thread you created. This mean it behave normally like clicking on a `button` triggers a `button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)` event. No special thread involved whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks @Franck I will review this and get back to you if any issues.

Comment: I am going to start working on your suggestions but question @Franck will it work the same if I change from a listbox to a CheckedListBox? because we are planning to use that instead of the listbox? please let me know.

Comment: I don't have Visual Studio at hand right now but it should by replacing the `ListBox` with `CheckedListBox`. Just need to make sure `CheckedListBox` can also do `CheckedListBox.Items.Add()` otherwise just correct the method `AddItem` inside the class to the correct way to add an item into that control.

Comment: thanks, I do have one question. 1) the custom `public class ListBoxWithEvents : ListBox` will have to be its own separate class?. 2) with these changes I won't need the thread that reads the data coming from the telnet port 23 from method ServerSocket? can you actually implement the code you added it to my code I added it my question? I have added it the main class so you can see how my main class calls the methods from class TelnetConnection.

Comment: 1- it has to be an external class, you can create a new class and put both the custom control and the event there like i did. 2- Yes you still need it, it doesn't affect anything on that side. 3- add the 2 class in 2 files if you want doesn't matter. Add the control on the window. Add the event and change the line i gave you to change in your second class (last code sample)

Comment: How do I compile the code so I can see the new ListBoxWithEvents in the toolbox? having an issue seeing that so I can replace it with my current listbox.

Comment: I think I got it, this is what I did let me know if is correct, I added the ListBoxItemEventArgs and the ListBoxWithEvents  in to external classes, then I drag the ListBoxWithEvents listbox class to the toolbox window then from there I dragged the ListBoxWithEvents listbox to the windows form and replaced it with my original class and then double click the itemadd to the main form, let me know if this correct process?

Comment: @NewCoder, yes that's is, as simple as that. Once the control on the form is that new one you can add as many new functions inside the custom class you want and you won't have to remove and add it again. It's 100% extensible without more headache.

Comment: now with all these changes made, now what I need from my first question is to add received the data from listbox to a normal like a list<> so every time the listbox receives that data from port 23 it will also be add it to the list<string>, so the purpose of that is that the list<string> will be receiving that data and then I will be doing the parsing because is a large barcode string and I will be parsing data from that barcode and then send the parsing data to a database which I know to do that, but only help will be to add the received data from the listbox add it to a list example on that?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not made for changing question. This lead to answer being completely invalid.

Comment: Sorry I not meant to change my question, I just need to send the data from the listbox to a list<string> then I will do the rest of the code. I just need a start base of the code, but your first solution did work on my question, just need the other part where send the data from the listbox data to a list<string>

Comment: any possible update on my last question on adding the coming in data from the listbox to a string list on a possible different method?

Comment: @NewCoder everything you need to do anything is there. Check the ItemAdded sample i gave you it already give you all the data.